# Can Squid (proxy server) handle HTTP 1.1 yet? And for Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, squid

I'm a fan of the Squid proxy server and have been using it at work for our a while .. on a windows 2008 server.

It cannot handle HTTP 1.1. Does anyone know if this is fixed/available for a windows release, yet?

Is it coming? Has the Squid development stalled / died off ??

Comment: We've been looking at replacing an old pix with a squid/pfsense box at a remote office -- I'd be curious to hear what the implications of the lack of HTTP 1.l support are -- does it refuse requests in 1.1 or pass them on in 1.0, and what issues does it create?

Comment: From our experience at our office, certain websites refuse to accept the request connection if it's not at least http1.1. I know this example is VERY trivial, but SETI is an example of this (and yes, seti has a manual setting to request in http 1.0). That said, nearly all places are a-ok, thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [project](http://devel.squid-cache.org/http11/) to add support. Since it has no progress since the end of 2006, either it's abandoned or merged in. I'm assuming the former and recommend you try to build with it patched in.

Answer (score 1):

In a limited sense, it's available.

See their roadmaps at http://wiki.squid-cache.org/RoadMap/Squid2 and http://wiki.squid-cache.org/RoadMap/Squid3

For some reason, I see it on the Squid 2 roadmap, but not on squid3.

Comment: the current release for squid is 2.7, for windows. so it's on the roadmap doesn't necessarily mean its in that build, right?